# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null - Error Message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here, I am hiding the div tag while change of dropdown menu. But when I select any value from dropdown, the message displayed as,

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById("leavetype").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Here is my code:

```js
var leave_type = $(this).attr('data_type');
    $('.status_approve').change(function() {
      if (leave_type == '4') {
        document.getElementByName("leavetype").style.visibility = "visible";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("leavetype").style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    });
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="leavetype">
  <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Emergency leave status</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <select name="emergencyleavestatus" id="emergencyleavestatus" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">Unpaid</option>
      <option value="1">Paid</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<select class="status_approve" data_type="<?php echo $row->leavetype_id;?>">
  <option value="">Select Action</option>
  <option value="1" <?php if($row->hr_approve=="1"){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Approve</option>
  <option value="2" <?php if($row->hr_approve=="2"){echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>Reject</option>
</select>
```

**Updated**

Comment: `document.getElementByName("leavetype")` is not valid JS. It would be `document.getElementsByName("leavetype")[0]` if you HAD an object with name="leavetype" which you do not.  `$("#leavetype")` would make more sense

Answer (score 1):

2 Problems;

1. you should define `leave_type` before you use it as a condition
2. `document.getElementByName("leavetype")`

Is not going to work unless there is a form element with `name="leavetype"`, if you want to select by ID, use;

```
document.getElementByID("leavetype")
```

Comment: you dont know if it is a global variable, so "first" is not really a problem :)

Comment: I suppose that's true. But as this is all the code we have to go on, it's best to make the guy aware that it needs defining, just in case :)

Comment: IF leave_type wasn't defined, the console would have reported it. The error is another

Comment: Again true, but I have no idea if the user has shown me all available data or just a snapshot, so I think it's better to cover all bases. Granted though, chances are he would have mentioned it if that was also an error.

Comment: `document.getElementByName("leavetype")` is not valid JS. It would be `document.getElementsByName("leavetype")[0]`

Comment: You make a very good point mplungjan! It's necessary to select the element  index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you can use jQuery here to hide and show div, see below code

```
$('.status_approve').change(function(){
      var leave_type = $(this).attr('data_type');
      if(leave_type == '4')
      {
         $("#leavetype").show();
       }
      else
      {
        $("#leavetype").hide();
       }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Bhusan: But when I am going to use like this, the div tag is not opening with hide and show.

Comment: @ViralBhoot, is there any browser console error? Also, you have `leave_type` outside the change event handler, it should be inside it. See updated answer.

Comment: I updated as per you said but still it gives an error in console:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

When this error fired?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two things use `data-*` attribute on options:

```
<select class="status_approve">
  <option value="">Select Action</option>
  <option value="1" data-type="1">Approve</option> <!-- here -->
  <option value="2" data-type="4">Reject</option> <!-- here -->
</select>
```

Now you can use this script:

```js
$('.status_approve').change(function() {
  var leave_type = $(':selected', this).data('type');
  $("#leavetype").toggle(leave_type == '4');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="leavetype">
  <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Emergency leave status</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <select name="emergencyleavestatus" id="emergencyleavestatus" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">Unpaid</option>
      <option value="1">Paid</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<select class="status_approve">
  <option value="">Select Action</option>
  <option value="1" data-type="1">Approve</option>
  <option value="2" data-type="4">Reject</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why have data-type the same as the value? does not make any sense

Comment: Actually i thought to suggest with value but that could be other mean to the user. @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're not waiting for the DOM to be fully loaded before requesting one of its elements.

Pure JS solution:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
   // your JS here
}, false);
```

but since you're already using jQuery or you could put into a $(document).ready() and use @Bhushan Kawadkar solution for requesting an element:

```
$(function() {
   // your JS here
});
```